# Unable to run user service in Docker

Tags: docker, microservices

I'm trying to run my userService that is registered on eureka server. Below is the code for UserDockerFile

```
FROM openjdk
COPY ./target/user_service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar .
ENV EUREKA_INSTANCE_HOSTNAME=host.docker.internal
CMD ["java","-jar","user_service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Below is the user service `application.yaml`:

```yaml
server:
  port: 9001

spring:
  application:
    name: user-service

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
```

and here is the Eureka server `application.yaml`:

```yaml
server:
  port: 8761


eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
  server:
    waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address : true
```

Whenever I'm building the image and trying to run the service:

```
  docker run -it -p 9001:9001  user-service
```

I'm facing the error:

```
Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://localhost:8761/eureka/}, 
exception=I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8761/eureka/apps/": Connect to 
localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused; nested exception is 
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1] 
failed: Connection refused stacktrace=org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: 
I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8761/eureka/apps/": Connect to localhost:8761 
[localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused; nested exception is 
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1] 
failed: Connection refused
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:785)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:711)
```

Comment: `localhost` in Docker almost always refers to the current container, not another container or the physical host system.  Do you need to set a `EUREKA_INSTANCE_HOSTNAME` environment variable pointing somewhere else?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes! as localhost will only work in my local system , i need to deploy the dockerize code